# What's the most efficient way to draw classes?

Tags: c#, opentk

I am working on my first (2D) game, and I chose OpenTK. I only have one question though. Let's say I have a class called PhysicsObject. Each PhysicsObject instance should be drawn automatically when the class is created. This is how I am currently doing it.

Physics object class:

```
public class PhysicsObject {

    public PhysicsObject() {
        EventMan.draws.Add(Draw);
    }

    public void Draw() {
        // draw code here
    }

}
```

EventMan:

```
public static class EventMan {
    public static List<Action> draws = new List<Action>();
}
```

Main game drawing code:

```
game.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
{
    foreach(List<Action> draw in EventMan.draws.ToList()) {
        draw.Invoke();
    }
}
```

This does work, however I feel like this isn't the most efficient way to do it. Are there any other ways or am I correct?

TL;DR: I am trying to draw each instance of the class PhysicsObject automagically when created, so I am adding the draw method of the instance to a public static List. This list is accessed in the draw code and runs that draw code.

Comment: It looks fine to me. I think there are more important things - are you using VBOs and VAOs properly? Are you reusing your vertex/normal/etc. data for objects with the same models? Personally I would worry about performance later.

Comment: I'm not too sure what VBO's and VAO's are, however, yes, I'm reusing data. I'm just a little concerned that accessing a public static variable will wear down performance.

Comment: I don't think that should be a big problem. If you are using old-style OpenGL (like immediate mode - glBegin-glEnd), that will have a much worse effect on performance. If you're not sure what VBOs and VAOs are, I would suggest reading up on those, because that's how OpenGL is done today.